# Is it possible to convert minidump to core files on Windows?

Tags: windows, mingw, dump, google-breakpad

I'm trying to implement breakpad crash handler in our application which runs cross-platform.

I've had great success with the Linux build, however, on Windows, I've gotten as far as getting a crash dump, extracting symbols from the .exe using dump_syms utility, and using minidump_stackwalk to check out the crash and line number.

Unless I'm missing something, It's difficult(impossible) using only minidump_stackwalk to debug further (checking out local variables, etc). On Linux I've used a tool minidump-2-core to convert minidumps to core files that can be loaded in gdb. On Windows we use a MSYS2/MINGW64 environment to build the application. Is it possible to convert the minidumps to core and load them in a similar fashion ?

I understand that an alternative is using WinDbg, however I can't seem to extract symbols correctly from the .exe. Any tips on how I would do that ?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/master/docs/processor_design.md) it looks like the Windows-native minidump format is used. In that case you could try the [gdb-with-minidump-support](https://github.com/ssbssa/gdb/releases) I very recently made.

Comment: So how do i open the minidump in gdb ?

Comment: The [same way](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Invoking-GDB.html) you would open a core file on linux: gdb program.exe mini.dmp

Comment: Thanks, It kinda works, but having core files lets me load things in QtCreator (my IDE). When I configure this version of GDB, it complains that it doesn't have python support.

Comment: Also, I would be very interested if something doesn't work (you said it *kinda* works).

Comment: Will provide feedback as soon as i figure how things are supposed to work. Thanks !